# Blank survey response because of the page security validation has timed out

Tags: upgrade, claims-based-auth, survey

One of our customers reported that after the migration to SharePoint 2013, he started receiving blank survey responses despite that most of the survey questions are mandatory.

We checked number of online threads on the same issue and number of responses identified this behavior as a result of page security validation time out.

Here are our findings regarding this issue

- It is ***not*** happening at all in SharePoint 2010
- It is ***only*** happening in SharePoint 2013 (the default Windows claims–mode is used)
- In both 2010 & 2013 farms, the same security validation settings are applied and it is already enabled and the security validation interval is set to 30 mins.
- In 2013, if we try to submit all survey questions once i.e. all survey questions are entered, the survey response saved but ***blank***.
- In 2013, if we try to submit in number of postbacks i.e. the first post request to the server, we missed any of mandatory questions, the survey response is saved successfully i.e. 2nd post request to the server is working properly.
- We believe it is not browsed based, all the above tests are performed in IE, FF and Chrome.

So my questions are

- Is that an issue in SharePoint 2013? if so, how to fix it?
- Why by default user is not getting the famous SharePoint error "The security validation for this page has timed out etc..." and then user can refresh the page and submits again?

Comment: Is it possible that the Mastertitel contains any jquery or javascript that execute some code that Remove or clear the data from the survey? Are in the uls Logs any warnings?

Comment: @Sascha - I can't get you completely but no JavaScript code is used. It is just an out of the box survey. We search ULS logs for any entries related to that but with no hope.

Comment: You can inspect network request in developer toolbar and check what request or what resource is taking time to render. Due to which security validation may occur. Pleaser refer this link for the same: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @404: I tried that in a couple of browsers on working and non working environment but nothing has been identified that could result to the root cause of that issue in SP 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking SharePoint's service pack and build number, and making sure that you have the latest patch available. You can also review the changelog to see if there's any bug related to this particular Web Part.

All build numbers: http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx

Additionally, you can verify the following post and check if your configuration regarding Security Validation is correct:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888828

Comment: Regarding the security validation configuration, we already have checked that in both working and non-working environments and both are exactly the same.